# Can I check in all the way through?

Tags: indian-citizens, luggage, schengen-visas, madrid, star-alliance

I've the following trip booked.

Outward: New Delhi -> Madrid -> Sao Paulo

Return: Lima -> Madrid -> Delhi

The New Delhi -> Madrid and Madrid -> Delhi leg is done by Air India. The Madrid -> Sao Paulo, Lima -> Madrid leg is covered by LATAM. The travel agent issued one ticket but I have two separate PNRS. Both airlines are star alliance members. Can I check in all the way through?

I ask, as the traveller doesn't have a Madrid visa. Air India says she should be able to check in all the way through, LATAM says she cannot.

Regardless, does the traveller need a transit visa to go change flights? We can try managing with just Cabin luggage.

The traveller is an Indian Citizen, with no other residencies or permits for any other country apart from a 10 year valid Canadian Visa.

Answer (score 2):

The flight is technically valid and you will be having the visas required. Transit Visa is not needed anyway for passengers having a canadian visa. However, these are the risks.

- If there is two tickets with two separate PNR, you won't get the second boarding pass from India and below case happens.

From Madrid airport website:

> Note that if you **do not have a boarding pass for your next flight**
>   and/or you have to need to pick up your luggage that is not checked to
>   destination, you must leave the boarding area, pass **through
>   immigration controls if any, and make a new check-in** to your airline
>   check-in counter. Then you will need to pass through security
>   checkpoints to re-enter the boarding area.

https://www.aeropuertomadrid-barajas.com/eng/flight-connections.htm

- Even if you make with a cabin bag, you are more likely to deny boarding from India itself, as airlines tends to err towards caution.
- If your first flight is delayed by any chance, you won't get any compensation or alternate route for second and you probably have to pay from your pocket.

So, its risky. Check whether its a single ticket from India to Brazil. If not, get travel agent to rebook it. Check with Air India anyway, before making any changes.

Comment: It is one ticket! Air India website has the Lat Am ticket number. Different PNRs a Air India has a 5 character Limit while LatAm accepts 6.

Comment: Then it won't be an issue. You will get both boarding passes from India most likely. Even if its not, you can approach an airside transfer desk to collect.

You call and confirm with Air India regarding check through.